# "was unexpected at this time." when running .cmd file through command line in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm getting the error "1JDa:~1JDa:~1 was unexpected at this time." when trying to run the following .cmd through the command line:

```
Call :GetDateTime Year Month Day
Call :SubtractDate %Year% %Month% %Day% -1 Ret

SET mes=%Ret:~0,2%
SET dia=%Ret:~3,2%
SET ano=%Ret:~6,4%



:SubtractDate Year Month Day <+/-Days> Ret
::Adapted from DosTips Functions::
setlocal & set a=%4
set "yy=%~1"&set "mm=%~2"&set "dd=%~3"
set /a "yy=10000%yy% %%10000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"
if %yy% LSS 100 set /a yy+=2000 &rem Adds 2000 to two digit years
set /a JD=dd-32075+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4
if %a:~0,1% equ + (set /a JD=%JD%+%a:~1%) else set /a JD=%JD%-%a:~1%
set /a L= %JD%+68569,     N= 4*L/146097, L= L-(146097*N+3)/4, I= 4000*(L+1)/1461001
set /a L= L-1461*I/4+31, J= 80*L/2447,  K= L-2447*J/80,      L= J/11
set /a J= J+2-12*L,      I= 100*(N-49)+I+L
set /a YYYY= I, MM=100+J, DD=100+K
set MM=%MM:~-2% & set DD=%DD:~-2%
set ret=%MM: =%/%DD: =%/%YYYY: =%
endlocal & set %~5=%ret%

:GetDateTime Year Month Day Hour Minute Second
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
( ENDLOCAL
     IF "%~1" NEQ "" set "%~1=%YYYY%" 
     IF "%~2" NEQ "" set "%~2=%MM%" 
     IF "%~3" NEQ "" set "%~3=%DD%"
     IF "%~4" NEQ "" set "%~4=%HH%" 
     IF "%~5" NEQ "" set "%~5=%Min%"
     IF "%~6" NEQ "" set "%~6=%Sec%"
)
exit /b
```

I don't have experience with these scripts, so maybe I've got a basic error? Thank you.

Comment: If you took the code from DosTips, why didn't you just ask the question over there.  We do have a forum over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing some exit after you call your subroutines and get the result. Add `exit /b` after the `SET ano=%Ret:~6,4%` line and you will be fine.

Comment: And also after the last line in :SubtractDate, otherwise calling :SubtractDate also calls :GetDateTime.

Comment: Yeah, that too. I fixed it while I was testing your code but forgot about it. :)